# Wanted but not invoked ... Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: email, testing, mockito, jakarta-mail

I'm doing a little test to an Email sending service
It just a simple JavaMailSender service and i was hoping to make an integration test for it

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MailingTest {

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender = mock(JavaMailSender.class);

    private ArgumentCaptor<MimeMessage> messageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MimeMessage.class);

    private Mailing mailing = new Mailing();

    @Test
    public void sendEmail() throws Exception {
        mailing.sendEmail();
        verify(javaMailSender).send(messageCaptor.capture());
        System.out.println("Result text" + messageCaptor.getValue());
        MimeMessage message = messageCaptor.getValue();
        message.setSubject("My Subject");
        message.setFrom("test@gmail.com");
        message.setText("Hello world");
        assertThat(message.getSubject()).isEqualTo("My Subject");
        assertThat(message.getAllRecipients().toString()).isEqualTo("test@gmail.com");
        assertThat(message.getFrom().toString()).isEqualTo("testingSender@gmail.com");
        //assertThat(message.getContent()).isInstanceOf(String.class);
        assertThat(message.getContent().toString()).isEqualTo("Hello world");
    }
}
```

And i keep getting the following warning and it just stops at the Verify line
been kinda stuck

```
Wanted but not invoked:
javaMailSenderImpl.send(
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at com.example.demo.MailingTest.sendEmail(MailingTest.java:39)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
javaMailSenderImpl.send(
    <Capturing argument>
);
```

Comment: how does your mock `JavaMailSender` get into the `Mailing` instance?

Comment: i use `javaMailSender.send(message.getMimeMessage());` to send Emails

Comment: Did you define the behaviour of the mocking object javaMailSender???

Comment: Sorry im soo new into programming ... I don't think i defined the behaviour of the mocking object